# Default login screen gone, how to revert?

Tags: 12.04, login, lightdm, desktop-background

i just installed 12.04 and was playing around, i dont remember what i did, now after one logout beautiful default login screen has changed into gray area, help needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay heres what to do-

open the terminal and enter the following command-

> ```
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
> ```

then you will get the following screen-

[image]

click on okay.you will get this screen with lightdm as atleast one of the options.-

[image]

Select `lightdm`.Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and logout to get the desired screen :)